# Qt : How to debug a bad alloc exception in QByteArray?

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray, bad-alloc

I have a `QNetworkReply` and I want to store the downloaded bytes in a `QByteArray`.

```
connect(_replyRef, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(PushDownloadedBytesToFile()));
void PushDownloadedBytesToFile()
{
     _internalBufferBytes.append(_replyRef->readAll());
}
```

The problem is that I get a `bad alloc` when the size is approximately 33552950.

I do not understand what is the problem or how can I debug this.

Comment: What about not reading all of the buffer, but chunk by chunk? This file is 32Mb, next one can be 512Mb. Handling of such large files should be done piece by piece.

Comment: Well... I read it chunk by chunk , but I need to have 40Mb in buffer for ..... reasons

Comment: There could be two reasos for bad alloc: not enough memory and corrupt heap. 40MB seems a pretty normal size these days, so `valgrind` is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From you comment, regarding maintaining 40 MB in buffer, I'd suggest to reserve this much memory (more would be better) in advance using [`QByteArray::reserve()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#reserve) API. But, with `QByteArray`, you have to maintain the total size, consumed size, current index, etc.

Another solution could be to use `QString` with [reserve()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#reserve). You wouldn't have to maintain the details. You can simply use [`QString::append()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#append) and then convert it to `QByteArray` using [`QString::toUtf8()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toUtf8) whenever you need it.